# Not Able to Access the function from different Component

Tags: reactjs

I am working tic-tac-toe game here. I don't know what's wrong with my code am not able to access the function from other component.

```
import React from "react";
import '../App.css';
class Choosechar extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {};
    this.onRadioSubmmit = this.onRadioSubmmit.bind(this);
  }
  onRadioSubmmit() {
    this.props.charSelect(this.state)
  }
  render() {
    var showMenu = (this.props.menuVisible) ? 'show' : 'hide';
    return (
      <div className="App-main-content">   
          <div className={showMenu}>
              <div className="">
                  <div className="center">
                    <h1>Do you want to play as <b>X</b> or <b>O</b>?</h1>
                    <button id="x-char" className="xo-button x" onClick={this.onRadioSubmmit}>X</button>                    
                    <button id="o-char" className="xo-button o" onClick={this.onRadioSubmmit}>O</button>
                  </div>
                 </div>
              </div>       
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Choosechar;
```

in the above code am trying the to display character user wants to play whether the user can select 'X' or 'O'

```
Game.js
import React from "react";
import WinLine from './Gameboard/WinLine';
import Board from './Gameboard/Board';
import Choosechar from './Choosechar';
import '../App.css'
const winCombos = [
    [0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8],   //horizontal
    [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8],   //vertical
    [0, 4, 8], [6, 4, 2]               //diagonal
  ];
class Game extends React.Component {    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            gameBoard:   Array.from(Array(9).keys()),
            menuVisible: true,
            showLine:    false,
            turn:        'X',
            turnToggler: 'X',
            user:        '',
            ai:          '',
            result:      '',
            winLine:     ''
          }
          this.minMax        = this.minMax.bind(this);
          this.gameOver      = this.gameOver.bind(this);
          this.checkWin      = this.checkWin.bind(this);
          this.checkTie      = this.checkTie.bind(this);
          this.bestSpot      = this.bestSpot.bind(this);
          this.startGame     = this.startGame.bind(this);
          this.charSelect    = this.charSelect.bind(this);
          this.changeTurn    = this.changeTurn.bind(this);
          this.handleClick   = this.handleClick.bind(this);
          this.emptySquares  = this.emptySquares.bind(this);
          this.playSound     = this.playSound.bind(this);
        }
        startGame() {
            //initialize start state
            this.setState({
              gameBoard:   Array.from(Array(9).keys()),
              menuVisible: true,
              showLine:    false,
              turn:        'X',
              turnToggler: 'X',
              user:        '',
              ai:          '',
              result:      '',
              winLine:     '',
            });
            //clear the board spaces of any text/styling
            let cells = document.querySelectorAll('.cell');
            for (let i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
              cells[i].innerText = '';
              cells[i].style.backgroundColor = 'initial';
              cells[i].style.pointerEvents = 'initial';
            }
          }
          
          charSelect(e) {    
            //assign selection to user, assign ai not selected
            debugger;
            let userCharacter = e.currentTarget.innerHTML;
            let aiCharacter = (userCharacter === 'X') ? 'O' : 'X';
            //update game state
            this.setState((prevState, props) => {
              return {
                user: userCharacter,
                ai: aiCharacter,
                menuVisible: false
              }
            });
            //default start char is 'X', if user selects 'O' invoke ai to go
            if (aiCharacter === 'X') {
              this.changeTurn(this.bestSpot(), aiCharacter);
            }
          }                        
        
          render() {
            var showPlayButton = (this.state.result === '') ? 'invis' : 'vis d-flex justify-content-center';
            return (
              <div>
                <div className={showPlayButton}>
                  <button id="replay-button" className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.startGame}>Play Again</button>
                </div>
                <Choosechar
                  menuVisible={this.state.menuVisible}
                  charSelect={this.props.charSelect}  
                />
              </div>
            );
          }
}

export default Game;
```

[Hi abhijeet thanks as per your updated code have updated mine but am still getting error have added the screenshot as well please have look at it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3l8XU.png)

Comment: Which function are you having trouble with? Also, your constructor should be `constructor(props) { super(props); ...`

Comment: @CharlesBamford am not able to access Charselect function from Game component

Comment: Abhijeet has the right of it, you are not accepting props in your Choosechar component though. Have you updated the constructor as I indicated above?

Comment: @CharlesBamford yup have updated but still this.props.charselect is undefined

Answer (score 0):

You need to change "**this.props**" to "**this**"

```
<Choosechar menuVisible={this.state.menuVisible} charSelect={this.charSelect}/>
```

More about "**this**" [here](https://medium.com/byte-sized-react/what-is-this-in-react-25c62c31480)

As well as you need to pass "**props**" in **super()** in "Choosechar" class component to use "**this**" further in component

```
class Choosechar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
```

more about **super** [here](https://medium.com/@jbbpatel94/why-do-we-write-super-props-fc367074a2af)

Comment: Hi Abhijeet have tried removing props as per you have showed but am still not able to access charSelect function from another component as its showing this.props.charSelect is undefined any suggestions?

Comment: @syedkhalandar Please have a look, I have updated the answer now